# Android - Sync document file in the Google Drive with the local changes

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-file, google-drive-android-api, google-play-developer-api

I am implementing an application which can sync a document which is in google drive. As the first step, I could make initial contacts with the Drive and I could take the file id for selected file and other metadata.

But as the next step, I need to sync with the file on the google drive. When the user is updating the local document I need to sync the updated texts and other stuff with Google Drive.

Is this possible or not?. If it is possible, What is the code?

Answer (score 0):

When you [open a file in drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files) local syncing happens.

> The DriveFile.open method retrieves the locally synced file resource
>   and opens it. If the file is not synced with the local storage, it
>   retrieves the file from the Drive service and returns a DriveContents
>   resource. For example:

```
 DriveFile file = ... file.open(mGoogleApiClient,
 DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
         .setResultCallback(contentsOpenedCallback);
```

> A DriveContents resource contains a temporary copy of the file's
>   binary stream which is only available to your application. If multiple
>   applications are accessing the same file, there are no race conditions
>   between DriveContents resources. In this situation, the last write
>   operation will be the final state of the content.
>
> Handling the response requires you to check if the call was successful
>   or not. If the call was successful, you can retrieve the DriveContents
>   resource. This resource contains methods to retrieve an InputStream or
>   ParcelFileDescriptor to read the file's binary contents